# Should upright math symbols stay upright when the context is italicized?

Tags: notation, convention

Consider the smallest infinite ordinal ω. Notice that it's typeset upright by default to denote that the meaning of the symbol is fixed.

In normal text this causes no problems:

> Now we present the specification of traffic lights as a machine with labeled transitions via regular and ω-regular expressions.

However, text (e.g., in titles) is often emphasized by making it italic. Therein, you can typeset italics *ω*:

> *Example 1.2.3 (Specification of traffic lights as a machine with labeled transitions via regular and ω-regular expressions)*  In the context of Example 1.2.1 consider […]

Or you can typeset upright ω:

> *Example 1.2.3 (Specification of traffic lights as a machine with labeled transitions via regular and* ω-*regular expressions)*  In the context of Example 1.2.1 consider […]

Independent of how folks do it when they are out of time and what various typesetting programs produce on various input, how ***should*** it be done correctly™ or properly™ and why? (The publisher's guidelines don't say anything on the matter.)

Comment: I think the practical approach is to follow your editor's guidelines.

Comment: @Gae.S. The publisher's guidelines are silent wrt. this matter. Of course, the corrector might have their 5 cents, but what they say is most often just a “suggestion”. They are also often simply nonmath folks.

Comment: Just like this is a nonmath issue: it's a typographical issue, in regard to which they know better.

Comment: Anyways, I would say that there is a good argument to have symbols be font-independent. $\omega$ becomes a standalone symbol the moment it's established to indicate a certain ordinal, and it should remain unchanged throughout.

Comment: @Gae.S. The publishers may also push the ball back similarly, saying “follow the conventions of your subject”. Pushing the ball back relieves the person being asked, but it is not helpful to the person asking the question. As for the font-independence, there is a good point in what you say. However, this not the full truth. E.g., if your font is heavy, you would probably typeset ALL your maths in the same weight, i.e., heavy. If you originally had bold letters, you would probably make them heavier than your current heavy font. This works well for the weight, but what about italicized/upright ?

Comment: Greek letters are normally set in italics even when the context is not.

Comment: @MJD No, that's NOT how I know it. I see that fixed-meaning Greek letters (we are not speaking about variables here, but about fixed-meaning constants and functions!) are normally NOT set in italics (though exceptions exist). They are normally (i.e., when the context is upright) set upright. A standard example is π, the ratio of the circumference or a circle to its diameter. The smallest infinite ordinal ω is another example. The Landau notation Ω and Θ are other examples.

Answer (score 1):

All languages, including technical language for mathematics, are determined by usage, and not by what any authority says. See the classic [Descriptive vs Prescriptive](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/resource/what-correct-language)  approaches in linguistics. As such, there isn't a ''correct" answer, rather there are norms that people tend to follow, and these may change over time.

From what I've seen, it is customary to emphasize in upright text by italicizing, and to emphasize in italics text by making it upright. Also, I've noticed that numbers, functions, operators, and mathematical symbols in general are written in displaystyle, even when in they are in the middle of the text, which makes them upright.

So, for example, in your question I would typeset the $\omega$ upright in the text. But there isn't a ''proper" way to do it, just norms and personal preference.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly why I wrote correctly™ and properly™, not correctly and properly.

Comment: I would not call typographical rules a matter of *linguistics*.